# Should I always compile Ajv schema in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ajv

I want to use the [Ajv validator](https://ajv.js.org/) to validate the request bodies of my `express` app.

To use the validator, we first need to compile the schema we want to test against, and then run the validation, like this:

```js
const Ajv = require('Ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv();

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['username', 'password'],
  properties: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 3,
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 8,
    },
  },
};

/* What we want to validate */
const body = {
  username: 'johndoe',
  password: 'secret'
};

/* We compile the validator */
const validate = ajv.compile(schema.query)

/* We test our data to see if it is valid */
const valid = validate(body)
```

Should I always compile the validator when my endpoints are called, and so include it inside my routes, or can I leave the compile process outside the route body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying out Josh Wulf's answer, I confirmed that it works compiling the validator outside the route's handler.

Although it works as intended and it's possible to compile outside the route's handler, I noticed it comes with a drawback.

The method of knowing which errors were detected by the validator is by calling `validate.errors`:

```js
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var valid = validate(data);

if (!valid) {
  console.log(validate.errors);
}
```

Because of this, we should not compile the validator outside of the route's handler, as there could be concurrency problems.

As the validator is the same across different requests to the same route, accessing the validator's `errors` property could return another client's errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile it once, outside the route handler, and reuse the compiled schema in the handlers.

This will improve performance - you only need to compile it when it changes.

Comment: And could I leave the `compile` just in the same file, outside and before my route handlers?

Comment: Yes, you sure can.

Comment: Although this could bring performance improvements, it has a big concurrency problem. Check my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

I think we should compile it once and reuse the compiled schema in the handlers.

At first, it might seem like it would cause a concurrency problem but it's not an `async` method to cause the **concurrency problem**.

Comment: If you just compile it once, validate.errors could be returning another client's errors, which is not ideal

Comment: Hello! It doesn't show another client's error. Everytime validate function runs, it contains the latest data. Since Javascript runs on a single thread, it doesn't cause any concurrency problem as long as we are accessing the value immediately. 

You can go through my runkit https://runkit.com/sh3rl0ck/ajv-validation-errors